# How do I create a form that sends the user to the path they enter?

Tags: html, forms

I would like to have a form on a page that asks the user to input a value. Upon hitting the "submit" button, I'd like for that value to be placed in a URL and the user be taken to that page. For instance - if the user inputs:

```
this-is-what-the-user-enters
```

Then upon hitting "submit", their browser then goes to this page:

```
http://my-website.com/this-is-what-the-users-enters
```

I'm sure this is simple, but solutions I have found elsewhere all end up included a "?" in the resulting URL string.

Here's what I've tried:

```
<script> 
function process() {
    var url="http://name.com/" + document.getElementById("url").value; 
    location.href=url; return false; 
} 
</script>
```

And then putting a form in the HTML:

```
<form onSubmit="return process();">
    URL: <input type="text" name="url" id="url"> <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

That gets the value from the form, but it adds a ? to the resulting URL.

Comment: have you used Jquery  or javascript ?

Comment: What language are you using to process the data you get?

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include what you've tried so far?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? You're reinventing the hyperlink and if a user types in an invalid URL, they'll get a 404 error. If it's a requirement for you, you're going to need more than just HTML to accomplish this. You're either going to need a server-side language or Javascript to accomplish this.

Comment: I've tried putting a script in the header of the page:

`<script>
function process()
{
var url="http://name.com/" + document.getElementById("url").value;
location.href=url;
return false;
}
</script>`

And then putting a form in the HTML:

`<form onSubmit="return process();">
URL: <input type="text" name="url" id="url"> <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>`

That gets the value from the form, but it adds a ? to the resulting URL.

Comment: I included your attempted code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is as simple as it gets

```
<input id="url"/>
<input type="button" onclick="document.location='http://my-website.com/' + document.getElementById('url').value" value="Go!"/>
```

Comment: Logan - thanks to you as well for offering a solution. In trying what you suggested - anyway to get "?url" out of the resulting URL?

Comment: well there shouldn't be any `?` because there is no functionality that would add it. There is no `form` required for this code. Just the two inputs. do you have an example in which you get a `?`?

Comment: I'm sorry - I put the code you suggested inside a <form> argument. 

This is going to work. Thanks for your time!

Comment: great...mark this as the answer so that people don't think you are still having an issue

Comment: I did - hope that worked (I'm still figuring out proper etiquette around StackOverflow).

Is there an attribute inside the <input> tag for the text on the submit button?

Answer (score 1):

Broadly, there are two ways to solve this.

1. Write something on your server to redirect the user to the path entered in the form.
2. Use JavaScript to set `window.location.pathname` to the value that the user enters, for example:

   ```
   <form action="#" method="GET" onsubmit="window.location.pathname = this.path.value; return false;">
       <label for="url">URL:</label> <input id="url" name="path" type="text"> <input type="submit">
   </form>
   ```

(In a real site you might not include the JavaScript in the `onsubmit` attribute, although for something tiny like this, it might actually be the best way to do it.)

Comment: Paul - thanks for your solution. Any way to get the resulting URL to not have "?path" included?

Comment: @HalAtkins: oops, I should have put `this.path.value`, not `this.path`. Fixed now; try that.

Comment: @HalAtkins: and for a working demon, see http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/test-pages/pathform/

Comment: Yeah - weird. Changing that variable in onsubmit - the result still included "?path" in the resulting URL. 

I get that the "path" comes from the name of the input - any idea on how to leave them out, however?

Comment: @HalAtkins: I'm not seeing ?path in the resulting URL. Are you seeing that on my working demo (http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/test-pages/pathform/)? If so, what browser are you using, and is JavaScript turned off in it?

Comment: Your solution works as well - thanks!.

(When I first tried your second solution, I was doing something incorrectly).

Comment: @HalAtkins: ah, got it. Excellent, glad to hear it.